# Running a compiler in parallel with java.utils.concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, java-threads

I am making a compiler for a language in Java and I want it to compile many files in parallel.

I have my class `Compiler.java` that has the constructor `Compiler(String fileName)` and the method `compile()`
So to compile a single file in my main all I do is :

```
Compiler c1 = new Compiler("file1.c");
c1.compile();
```

What I want to do is for a list of files ( lets say ["file1.c", "file2.c", "file3.c"] ) is executing the c1.compile(), c2.compile(), c3.compile() in parallel (c'i' being the compiler for file'i' ).

I am still a beginner in `Java.util.concurrent`. In C I just fork or use the POSIX thread library with the `join` method. But in Java I see there is more to it with things called thread pools etc. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thread pools are not unique to Java. Although, in some languages, the _standard_ library has one or more thread pool types, whereas in C or C++, you still either have to use a 3rd-party library, or else roll your own.

Comment: The idea of a thread pool is to avoid the overhead of creating a thread and tearing it down once per request in a server-ish environment by re-using them repeatedly.  For a compiler, this probably doesn't apply. Just create and exit the threads as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to use a thread pool in Java if all you want is a thread.* (Assuming you want to use threads at all **) Pretty much the simplest way to create a thread looks like this:

```java
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        ...code to be executed in the new thread goes here...
    });
    t.start();
    ...do other stuff concurrently with the new thread...
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // If your program doesn't use interrupts then this should
        // never happen. If it happens unexpectedly then, Houston! We
        // have a problem...
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

* You might *want* to use a thread pool if your program otherwise would create many short-lived threads. The purpose of a thread pool, just like any other kind of "xxxx pool," is to re-use threads instead of continually creating and destroying them. Creating and destroying threads is relatively expensive compared to the cost of the *tasks* that some programs want to run *in* those threads.

Pretty much the simplest way to use a thread pool looks like this:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

    final int N_THREADS = ...however many worker threads you think you need...;
    final int PRACTICALLY_FOREVER = 999;

    ExecutorService thread_pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N_THREADS);
    while (...still have work to do...) {
        thread_pool.submit(() -> {
            ...task to be executed by a worker thread goes here...
        });
    }
    thread_pool.shutdown();
    try {
        thread_pool.awaitTermination(PRACTICALLY_FOREVER, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // If your program doesn't use interrupts then this should
        // never happen...
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

** Some people think that threads are old-fashioned and/or low-level. Java has a whole other model for concurrency. You might want to take some time to learn about [*parallel streams*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).